# What geo chart library NyTimes is using?

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts, google-visualization, geo

I found this link

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/07/24/business/international/the-world-according-to-china-investment-maps.html?_r=1

[image]

It is also interactive.

Can I know what lib they are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Javascript assets, it looks like it's loading d3.js and topojson. The map itself is an SVG, so likely generated using D3.

Answer (score -1):

this page use one js file for draw chart : [chartbeat.js](http://chartbeat.com)
[download chartbear.js](https://static.chartbeat.com/js/chartbeat.js)